# Powershell prevent UTF8 conversion

Tags: powershell, encoding, utf-8, ascii

when I try to manipulate an .ini File with Powershell it always switch the encoding to UTF-8.

My Code:

```
Get-Content -Path "./update.ini" -Encoding ascii | Out-File -FilePath "ascii_update.ini" -Encoding ascii
```

The file needs to stay ASCII, so how can I disable this behaviour or how to switch it back to ASCII?

Comment: Are you saying that `Out-File ... -Encoding ASCII` produces an UTF8-encoded file? Or are you asking how to make `Out-File -Encoding` always default to `ASCII` unless otherwise specified?

Comment: update.ini is an ASCII File
After running this command I get ascii_update.ini, which is UTF8 encoded...

I want to stay in ASCII or alternatively I want to convert it back to ASCII

Comment: And how exactly are you asserting that the encoding of the resulting file is UTF8 and not ASCII? If the input file contains only ASCII characters, the resulting byte stream is exactly the same in both encoding schemes :)

Comment: German characters will not be shown correctly in further processes + notepad shows it as UTF-8 on the bottom right side.

Comment: Aha, so the input is _not_ pure ASCII :) It sounds like you want to retain _OEM encoding_, not ascii encoding

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> German characters will not be shown correctly

Given that you don't want UTF-8 encoding yet you want German umlauts, **what you're looking for is *ANSI* encoding, not *ASCII*.**

- **In *Windows PowerShell***, ANSI encoding is the *default* encoding used by [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) and [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) (but *not* [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file), which defaults to "Unicode" (UTF-16LE)), so all you need is the following:

```bash
# Windows PowerShell: ANSI encoding is the default for Get-Content / Set-Content
Get-Content ./update.ini | Set-Content ascii_update.ini
```

- **In *PowerShell (Core) 7+***, (BOM-less) UTF-8 is now the default, across *all* cmdlets, so you must request ANSI encoding *explicitly*, using `-Encoding`

  - Unfortunately, whereas `Default` refers to the system's active ANSI encoding in *Windows PowerShell*, in PowerShell (Core) it now refers to UTF-8, and there is *no* predefined `ANSI` enumeration value to complement the `OEM` value - this baffling omission is discussed in [GitHub issue #6562](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6562).
  - Therefore, you must determine the active ANSI code page explicitly, as shown below.

```bash
$ansiEnc = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ANSICodePage
Get-Content -Encoding $ansiEnc ./update.ini |
  Set-Content -Encoding $ansiEnc ascii_update.ini
```

---

> notepad shows it as UTF-8 on the bottom right side.

ASCII encoding is a *subset* of UTF-8 encoding, which is why most editors show pure ASCII files as UTF-8, because they are by definition also valid UTF-8 files.

Note that if you save or read text that contains non-ASCII characters with `-Encoding ASCII`, the non-ASCII characters are "lossily" transcoded to *verbatim `?` characters*.

---

##### Optional reading: managing INI files as UTF-16LE ("Unicode") encoded, support via Windows API functions:

[zett42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7571258/zett42) points out that the [`WritePrivateProfileString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-writeprivateprofilestringw) and [`GetPrivateProfileString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofilestringw)
Windows API functions interpret INI files as follows:

- If a file has a UTF-16LE ("Unicode") BOM, it is read and updated as such.
- Otherwise, it is invariably interpreted as ANSI-encoded (even if it has a different Unicode encoding's BOM, such as UTF-8).

If you let `WritePrivateProfileString` create an INI file *implicitly*, it is always created *without* a BOM, and therefore treated as ANSI-encoded (even if you use the Unicode version of the API function). If you try to write non-ANSI-range Unicode characters to such a file, they are quietly and lossily transcoded as follows: either to an ASCII-range equivalent, for accented letters, if applicable (e.g., `ă` is transoced to `a`); otherwise, to verbatim `?`

Thus, creating the INI file of interest *explicitly* with a *UTF-16lE BOM* is necessary in order to maintain the file as UTF-16LE-encoded and therefore enable full Unicode support.

Thus, you could create the INI file initially with a command such as `Set-Content -Encoding Unicode ./update.ini -Value @()`, which creates an (otherwise) empty file that contains only a UTF-16LE BOM, and then stick with `-Encoding Unicode` if you need to manipulate the file directly.

[This MIT-licensed Gist](https://gist.github.com/mklement0/006c2352ddae7bb05693be028240f5b6) (authored by me) contains module file `IniFileHelper.psm1`, whose `Get-IniValue` and `Set-IniValue` functions wrap the above-mentioned Windows API functions, with the crucial difference that when `Set-IniValue` *implicitly* creates an INI file it uses UTF-16LE encoding.

The following, self-contained example demonstrates this:

```bash
# Download the module code and import it via a session-scoped, dynamic module.
# IMPORTANT: 
#   While I can personally assure you that doing this is safe,
#   you should always check the source code yourself first.
$null = New-Module -Verbose -ScriptBlock ([scriptblock]::Create((Invoke-RestMethod 'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/mklement0/006c2352ddae7bb05693be028240f5b6/raw/1e2520810213f76f2e8f419d0e48892a4009de6a/IniFileHelper.psm1')))

# Implicitly create file "test.ini" in the current directory,
# and write key "TestKey" to section "Main", with a value
# that contains an ASCII-range character, an ANSI-range character,
# and a character beyond either of these two ranges.
Set-IniValue test.ini Main TestKey 'haäă'

# Now retrieve the same entry, which should show the exact
# same value, 'haäă'
# Note: If there is a preexisting "test.ini" file that does NOT
#       have a UTF-16LE BOM, the non-ANSI 'ă' character would be
#       "best-fit" transcoded to ASCII 'a'.
#       Other non-ANSI characters that do not have ASCII-range analogs
#       would be lossily transcoded to verbatim '?'
Get-IniValue test.ini Main TestKey
```

Comment: Awesome, that feature of the API isn't well documented (there is one sentence in the `WritePrivateProfileString` documentation, but it isn't very clear), so thanks for the work here.